History of Invertible linear transformations
Who studied invertible linear transformations for the first time? I would guess these linear transformations weren't studied for the sake of studying invertible linear transformations, they probably were studied and developed as a helping tool for understanding other topics
What are some related references?

Basic linear algebra relates invertibililty of a linear transformation to the fact that a system of linear equations has a unique solution (as opposed to none, or infinitely many). Certainly people talked about this long before the notion of linear transformation was formalized.
